# How to convert a font file ttf into string data like vfs_fonts.js does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, truetype, pdfmake, node-pdfkit

I am planning to embed custom font ttf into pdfmake plugin. The documentation recommends to add the custom fonts to the vfs_fonts.js file.

```
 window.pdfMake = window.pdfMake || {}; window.pdfMake.vfs = {
  "Roboto-Italic.ttf": "AAEAAAASAQAABA",
  "Roboto-Medium.ttf": "AAEAAA",
  "MyFont.ttf":"???????????????????"
}
```

I  have MyFont.ttf file but I don't know how to convert that into string/encoded format. Is there anyway to do it programatically through javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a `base64` format.

There are many tools available online.

[Here is one](https://www.giftofspeed.com/base64-encoder/)

**Programatically :**

> In JavaScript there are two functions respectively for decoding and
>   encoding base64 strings:
>
> atob()
>
> btoa()
>
> The atob() function decodes a string of data which has
>   been encoded using base-64 encoding.
>
> Conversely, the btoa() function
>   creates a base-64 encoded ASCII string from a "string" of binary data.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)